How useful were the materials found by GNoME?
In November 2023 DeepMind used an AI system Graph Networks for Materials Exploration or GNoME (I have no idea where the ‘o’ comes from) to find 421,000 new materials. Way more than had been found before.
My question is whether or not some of these discovered materials have been proven useful or promising. I can’t appear to find any article on the substances that provides an update, even though it’s been several months.

+1 Welcome to our community!

Welcome! One thing I would note is several months isn't a lot of time in academic or industrial circles, particularly if you include both the time to experimentally characterize one/several of these materials and the time to actually get it published in some journal. Even if there has been some very fast progress and enough data collected to be published, if it was from an industrial research group, they might feel the need to hold onto that data until they can find a way to productize these new materials.
